# LAMP server software requirements

Tags: security, webserver, ubuntu-server, lamp

I'm building my first LAMP server to be used as both a remote testing server and as practice for building a web server.

I'm going to use Ubuntu Server with Apache2, PHP7, MySQL 5.7, OpenSSL and vsFTPd.

I understand how to install and use LAMP and ftp stacks in themselves, but what I don't know is what other software I'll need to make it secure.

It's going to be behind a Sonicwall, and I'm reading through [this article](http://tecadmin.net/security-tips-for-lamp-stack-on-linux/) for user, file and directory security, but what it doesn't talk about is protection from viruses, malicious code, and brute forcing from behind the network firewall. I understand the PHP code will need to take care of a lot of that, which I'm learning.

But do I need to install any additional software like an Anti-Virus, firewall, etc aside from the LAMP stack and FTP server?

P.S. I do plan to install WHM/cPanel and the dependencies for that, which I understand.

Comment: Basically what I'm finding around the web is that AV on LAMP is unnecessary unless I have a file server. So as long as I only accept certain media formats , I should be relatively safe for an unindexed web server and my PHP code is secure once I upload it to the remote site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Securing a web server is a large topic, more fit for a book (or series of books) than a Stack Exchange answer.  With that being said, I'll address a few points.

> but what it doesn't talk about is protection from viruses, malicious code, and brute forcing from behind the network firewall.

Generally speaking, we don't concern ourselves much with virus-type infections in Linux.  The target percentage of computers is much lower, the permissions systems (and things like SELinux) help prevent a lot of issues that would arise, and installation of software only from trusted software repositories help reduce this threat.

Keep your server up to date, subscribe to [the Ubuntu security announcement list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-security-announce), and don't run untrusted software.  And don't disable [AppArmor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor).

General advice in security circles is that once any sign of infection is found, you should nuke (erase) the server and start from scratch, rather than trying to clean out any infection.  To this end, you should configure (and test!) regularly-scheduled backups.  It's also a very good idea to use a configuration management tool (I like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/)) for all of your configuration, rather than doing it by hand, so that you can bring up another server instantly.

One final recommendation I have is to install [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).  It's most often used to protect against SSH brute-force attempts, but it also ships with configuration files for a number of other common brute-forced network services.  If you use Ansible, configuring it becomes much easier due to the presence of [includeable roles from their community repo](https://galaxy.ansible.com/detail#/role/1435).

> I should be relatively safe for an unindexed web server

There are bots constantly scanning the entire known IPv4 address space for servers, so you should never assume that simply because your server is not publicly linked to, it won't be found.